# Good reference for string diagrams

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation

I try to learn about string diagrams, like explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USYRDDZ9yEc).

First question: Is also some good *written* introduction to this topic?

Second question: I found [The Geometry Of Tensor Calculus](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/GTCII.pdf), which seems to be the right thing for me, but they are concerned with monodial categories, in contrary to the video which is concerned about natural transformations, it seems to me.  Is there some easy way to interpret the content of the paper in terms of natural transformations between functors between (non-monoidal) categories?

Comment: I'll just throw out there that Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra* is the best introductory category theory book I know of, by far. Not specifically for string diagrams, though.

Comment: Thank you!  Do you by any chance know which volume of the handbook contains the string diagrams?

Comment: there are no string diagrams in Borceux. I think he just meant it is the best overall text on category theory in general. The Catsters on youtube have a couple videos on string diagrams.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- John Baez, Aaron Lauda, *Higher-Dimensional Algebra V*, [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307200v3.pdf)
- Dan Mardsen, *Category theory using string diagrams*, [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.7220v2.pdf)
- Peter Selinger, *A survey of graphical languages for monoidal categories*, [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3347v1.pdf)

Comment: Recognizing that the OP is not (recognizably) about string-diagrams in a bicategorial context, but rather about the classical case of monoidal categories, I think one should add to this list [Schommer-Pries, Section A.4 herein](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1000). This is a useful six-page written introduction to some of the important issues in the bicategorical setting. Besides the 1-page introduction in Section 8 of Selinger's article cited above, it is the only introduction to string diagrams decidedly written with the bicategorical context in mind that is known to me.

Answer (score 1):

See also these [lecture notes](https://www.dtubbenhauer.com/qinvariants.pdf) by Daniel Tubbenhauer (with accompanying [lecture videos](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuFcVFHMIfhITJ_gj0fErofMljy-2YL2D)).